# Responsive website works fine on Firefox responsive mode, but not in Chrome or Device

Tags: ios, css, google-chrome, firefox, responsive-design

I built a website for myself which I believe is responsive as per my testing with Firefox's responsive mode. I tested all the pages with the iPhone resolution (375*667) both landscape and portrait mode and it worked great.

However when I try to open the same site in Chrome, it does not display properly. It also shows the same effect when viewed from an iPhone.

This is my site - http://v1chu.github.io/

The background images in used in section 2 and 3 are missing whereas it is working fine with Firefox (also in responsive mode). I can't see the background in my device as well.

Also the site content looks very small when viewed in Chrome and device. But it looks just fine when viewed in Firefox.

Please tell me if the way I have built the site is right or not ? Or if something that I have missed which messes up the site on Chrome and devices.

Comment: The issue with the text has to do with not using a _"responsive meta tag."_

Comment: does that mean Firefox adds the meta tag automatically when viewed in responsive mode ?

Comment: Possibly, don't know for sure. Doesn't matter though, you need to use a responsive meta tag if you want everything to work as expected on various devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're heading in the right direction.

#### Problem #1, Background Images

Your background images don't appear because you are using the [`background-attachment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment) property with the value `fixed`. It sets the background in relation to the viewport (browser window). You're basically pinning the background image to the top of the page and by the time you get to your 2nd and 3rd sections you've scrolled past the background image.

You have set `background-attachment` via the shorthand [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) property. Remove `fixed` from the `background` property.

`background: url( '../img/aboutme.jpg' ) no-repeat center;`

#### Problem #2, Text size

You need to use a responsive meta tag. Here's one that I use:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">`

Comment: Yup. These fixed the bugs. But the thing is, my background image gets skewed when I removed `fixed` from the `background` property. Previously, the content actually aligned with the Mac in the background (in Firefox). Can we make the background image not scale with the viewport width and height ?

Comment: Instead of using `background-size: 100% 100%;` use `background-size: cover;`. Note that the image will be cropped at the sides instead of being squished.

Comment: Yes , that fixed it. Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be here:

```
.s2 {

background: url(../img/aboutme.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;

}
```

I removed the fixed and the background displayed in chrome

```
s2 {

background: url(../img/aboutme.jpg) no-repeat center;

}
```

Comment: I believe if you just remove the "fixed" it will